# <Select> array element's change event will populate another <Select> element by jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 2  array elements. I tried to bind change event to first element so that the select change even will influence second element.
Example:

```
<select name="item1[]" id="item1[]">
  <option value="0">...</option>
  <option value="1">...</option>
  <option value="3">...</option>
</select>

<select name="item2[]" id="item2[]">
  <option value="0">...</option>
  <option value="1">...</option>
  <option value="3">...</option>
</select>

<select name="item1[]" id="item1[]">
  <option value="0">...</option>
  <option value="1">...</option>
  <option value="3">...</option>
</select>

<select name="item2[]" id="item2[]">
  <option value="0">...</option>
  <option value="1">...</option>
  <option value="3">...</option>
</select>
```

Accordingly there are more rows with item1 and item2 array element waiting for PHP process.

When item1 select will change then item2 will populate. but my following jquery function do not work even in item1 change event. I could not understand why bind function not working. I tried to use alert but not work.

```
<script>
$('#item1[]').each(function(index){
  $(this).bind("change", function(){
    another function call to populate item2
    alert($(this).val()); // not working
  });
});
</script>
```

Please help.

Regards.

Comment: The ID *must* be unique.

Comment: Is it a typo that both elements have **ID** `item1[]`? IDs have to be unique!

Comment: Your event is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/YD25J/).

Comment: Besides being unique, `[]` isn't valid...or really appropriate (IMO) for an ID (.e.g. your current issue with escaping), why not have the ID just be `item1`?

Comment: @Nick Craver You're quite right: *"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."* ( [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) )

Comment: @jensgram - be sure to note that's the HTML4 spec, not HTML5 ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver Oops, you're right.

Comment: As it is an array element then ID should not only item1 but item1[]. Am I right? My code will be like - <select name="item1[]" id="item1[]"> <option value="0">...</option> <option value="1">...</option> </select> <select name="item2[]" id="item2[]"> <option value="0">...</option> <option value="1">...</option> </select> <select name="item1[]" id="item1[]"> <option value="0">...</option> <option value="1">...</option> </select> <select name="item2[]" id="item2[]"> <option value="0">...</option> <option value="1">...</option> </select>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments, you need to escape those square brackets (or remove them from the ID attributes - they are only complicating things, and [invalid in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) as @jensgram points out):

```
$('#item1\\[\\]')
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thank you very much bro. Would you help me little bit more. How can I determine item2 index when item1 will change. Because of if the item[1] change  then only item2[1] will populate not other item2[..]

Comment: "... they are only complicating things" And [invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id), too.

Comment: About the invalid thing; sorry not to mention that the link covers HTML4. HTML5 seems to accept anything but whitespaces.

Comment: @Iqbal - I think you will need to paste the rest of your implementation into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The same id should not exist more than once in a document, jquery stops searching for domobjects as soon as it finds one id.

Also, [] is not valid in an id, see [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you do such a complicated call, but this should do it:

```
$('#item1\\[\\]').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

(provided that you have only one element with that ID).

`[]` are meta-characters for the attribute selector:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (`#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/@`) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, if you have an an element with `id="foo.bar"`, you can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

And btw if you have the square brackets for PHP, you don't need them in the ID. They only make sense in the `name` attribute.

Comment: Yes bro Felix. I need to keep it for PHP. I noticed that ID is not needed. Now my problem is to populate the same indexed item2[same index of item1] by mysql data.

Comment: @Iqbal: How are they positioned in your HTML? Does the `item2` always follow directly the corresponding `item1`? (i.e. is `item2` the next sibling of `item1`?)